# Swipe in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe

I have a listview. And I need to make something very easy to acces on the listview. So I want to make something like the Samsung contact list.

Can somebody help me where I need to start? (Maybe a code example or some explanation where to start?)

[image]

It is just that I want to make a listview with this kind of swipe mechanic. I don't want to remove a row or add a row. I just want a event behind it to do stuff when swiped. And the animation would be cool if it was something like that.

Comment: It is just that I want to make a listview with this kind of swipe mechanic. I don't want to remove a row or add a row. I just want a event behind it to do stuff when swiped. And the animation would be cool if it was something like that.

Comment: I've found this repo, it has all sorts of swipe related examples you might be able to use: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the libraries on github

1. [listview animations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)
2. [swipe to dismiss](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA)
3. Roman nurik's [Android-SwipeToDismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss)

Answer (score 1):

This '[SwipeToDismissUndoList](https://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList)' code might help you.